# How to fetch my gmail contact list's email addresses in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-plus

I want to access the google plus signed In user's connections email addresses in my app.

I followed [this doc](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) but it only returned me its name, image url not returning their emails.

I am able to get their email by following [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) but its returning me response in xml format and don't know its correct way or not.

Can anyone help me on how to get email ids or parse this xml?

Comment: any one have answer?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ using this jut need to read the docs little more and it work perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this in Swift 3:

https://github.com/kalvish21/google-contacts-swift3/tree/master/Google%20Contacts%20Viewer